# How to shard a tree data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, hashmap

We are storing some information in tree data structure (in memory). We have reached to a point where we cannot store this data in one single machine and need to shard it.

while sharding a hashmap (hash table) is straight forward as structure is linear, but how can shard a tree?

There are many questions like should we shard it horizontally or vertically, at which level? Since tree is dynamic, it can grow at any level.

Thanks

Comment: This question seems too broad, but you should then consider a different data structure, where you can work with fixed sized blocks that have multiple key/data pairs, possibly not completely occupying the block. A common structure is a B tree. But again, this question is too vague. It could have a chance if it actually described the problem being solved with this structure, so that we can propose alternatives for *that* particular need.

Comment: Thanks @trincot, we are building some sort of in-memory file system, where store directories and files. Like any file system, a directory can have other directories and files. Files are stored as byte array.

Comment: So this is  a problem that was already tackled in the early days of computers... Check how operating systems have mapped popular file systems in memory and on disk? One of the many examples: [FAT file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system)

Comment: Most people use a [B+-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) or a variant thereof. The idea is to make nodes as big that the consume between 50% and 100% of a fixed chunk size, e.g. 4KB.